# Python to have multiple correct answers

Tags: python

I am trying to have multiple answers to 1 question. How can I make that happen here?
I want all numbers between 10 and 20 to be correct, while everything else to be wrong:

```
print ("Say a number between 10 or 20 "
       "Only full numbers")

answer = 0

while answer != "10":

    answer = input()
    if answer == '10':
        print("Right!")
    else:
        print ("Wrong try again!")
```

Comment: What about `<` and/or `>`. Have a think about it mate.

Comment: print ("Say a number between 10 och 20 "
       "Only full numbers")

answer = 0

while answer != "10":

    answer = input()
    if answer == '10':
        print("Right!")
    else:
        print ("Wrong try again!")

Answer (score 5):

Cast to `int`, then compare:

```
answer = int(input())
if 10 <= answer <= 20:
    print("Right!")
else:
    print ("Wrong try again!")
```

Comment: You don't need the `and`.

Comment: Or `10 <= answer <= 20`.

Comment: Fun fact, you don't need the cast to `int` either if their answers aren't too wrong.

Comment: @gilch Thanks for suggestion to shorten the code to: `10 <= answer <= 20`

Comment: @HansMusgrave True, although for clarity I prefer to cast. "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: That makes sense. Strictly speaking you probably want a try/catch or something in case of parse errors, and it's unclear whether inputs like `'1_0'` should be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Convert input to integer to compare. Similar to @TimurShtatland's answer, but no need for the `and` logic

```
answer = int(input())
if 10 <= answer <= 20:
    print("Right!")
else:
    print ("Wrong try again!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```pytohn
print ("Say a number between 10 And 20 " "Only full numbers")
answer = 0
while answer not in range(10, 21):

    answer = int(input())
    if answer in range(10, 21):
        print("Right!")
    else:
        print ("Wrong try again!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have a cast to `int`, which might be beyond what you've learned (and might throw an error and break out of your program). For integers with a fixed number of digits you can compare their string representations just as well, so the following is ever so slightly more robust than some of the other options, depending on the exact behavior you'd like.

Do keep in mind that the other answers would accept inputs like `'    10'` and `'1_0'`, whereas the following solution will not.

```
answer = input()
if len(answer) == 2 and '10' <= answer <= '20':
    print("Right!")
else:
    print ("Wrong try again!")
```